# can't send data from react native to flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, react-native, fetch

I try to send data with the following code:

```
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("username", userName);
        console.log(data)
        var fetchOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
             "Accept": "application/json",
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
             'mode': 'no-cors',
             'cache': 'no-cache'
          },
          body: data
        }
        fetch(url, fetchOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {  
            responseJson = response.json();
            console.log(responseJson, response.status);
            if (response.status == 200) {
              alert('success！');
              this.state.code = false;
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

and in flask I received these data as as

```
    username = request.form['username']
    return jsonify({'data': 'Code received!'})
```

But this didn't work. it return the follwoing for `console.log(responseJson, response.status);`

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
} 200
```

Any idea about why this happened?

Comment: Put some `print` statements in your flask and look at console output from the server. I can promise you that `Promise` object is not coming from flask...

Answer (score 2):

response.json() returns a promise and should be resolved. 
Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json
If you do `.then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json))` you should see what you want to see